# Pandas - if one column contains a string, then all columns below for that product are true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

```
    df = {'product':['apple','apple','banana','banana','banana','banana'], 
         'date':['2021-01-01','2022-02-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-02-02','2021-09-01',
         '2021-12-31'], 
         'type1':['y', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'], 
         'type2':['y', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x','y']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

I want to add a column that is True if the product contains an x type in either column. But, for say banana, an x occurs on 2021-09-01, so all the banana after that will also be marked True, even if the particular row doesn't contain a 'y'.

```
    0   2021-01-01   y   y   False
    1   2022-02-01   x   y   True
    2   2021-01-02   y   y   False
    3   2021-02-02   y   x   True
    4   2021-09-01   y   x   True
    5   2021-12-32   y   y   True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) per group to forward fill the True values:

```
df['out'] = (df.filter(like='type').eq('x').any(1)
               .groupby(df['product']).cummax()
             )
```

output:

```
  product        date type1 type2    out
0   apple  2021-01-01     y     y  False
1   apple  2022-02-01     x     y   True
2  banana  2021-01-02     y     y  False
3  banana  2021-02-02     y     x   True
4  banana  2021-09-01     y     x   True
5  banana  2021-12-31     y     y   True
```

Comment: This works if the date columns are in order. But not if they aren't - you'd have to sort them.

Comment: @f2567 yes, you need the dates sorted (add `.sort_values('date')` as a first step if this is not the case)