# Make a column of the first time something occurs across multiple columns

Tags: dataframe

my code:

```
df = {'product':['apple','apple','banana','banana','banana','banana'], 
         'date':['2021-01-01','2022-02-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-02-02', '2021-09-01', '2021-12-31'],
         'date2': ['2021-01-03','2022-02-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-02-04', '2021-09-04', '2022-01-04'], 
         'type1':['y', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y'], 
         'type2':['y', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x','y']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.sort_values(by = ['product', 'date'])

df['out'] = (df.filter(like='type').eq('x').any(1)
               .groupby(df['product']).cummax()
             )
```

solution from: [Pandas - if one column contains a string, then all columns below for that product are true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73390240/pandas-if-one-column-contains-a-string-then-all-columns-below-for-that-produc)

gives:

```
     product date        date2     type1 type2 out
0   apple   2021-01-01  2021-01-03  y   y   False
1   apple   2022-02-01  2022-02-03  x   y   True
2   banana  2021-01-02  2021-01-04  y   y   False
3   banana  2021-02-02  2021-02-04  y   x   True
4   banana  2021-09-01  2021-09-04  y   x   True
5   banana  2021-12-31  2022-01-04  y   y   True
    enter code here
```

now I want to add a column (first_date) that gives the first date where 'out' is. But if it's from type1, then the date column should be date.

desired output:

```
       product     date      date2    type1 type2 out first_date
    0   apple   2021-01-01  2021-01-03  y   y   False  NA
    1   apple   2022-02-01  2022-02-03  x   y   True   2021-02-01
    2   banana  2021-01-02  2021-01-04  y   y   False  NA
    3   banana  2021-02-02  2021-02-04  y   x   True   2021-02-04
    4   banana  2021-09-01  2021-09-04  y   x   True   2021-02-04
    5   banana  2021-12-31  2022-01-04  y   y   True   2021-02-04
```

Comment: Haven't you already asked the first part of question (I recognize my code)? Why did you delete it?

Comment: Apologies I'm new to stackoverflow. I just undeleted it and referenced your code above. This is the second part

Comment: thanks for undeleting. I have to say this was quite bad practice (this felt a bit like "*I got what I wanted now bye and nevermind the other users*"), if everyone was doing it there would be no base of Q/A. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for the basics of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can `mask` and get the first date, then `transform` per group, then use boolean indexing to only assign where `out` is `True`:

```
s = (df[['date', 'date2']]
     .where(df[['type1', 'type2']].eq('x'). values)
     .bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
    )

df.loc[df['out'], 'first_date'] = s.groupby(df['product']).transform('first')
```

output:

```
  product        date       date2 type1 type2    out  first_date
0   apple  2021-01-01  2021-01-03     y     y  False         NaN
1   apple  2022-02-01  2022-02-03     x     y   True  2022-02-01
2  banana  2021-01-02  2021-01-04     y     y  False         NaN
3  banana  2021-02-02  2021-02-04     y     x   True  2021-02-04
4  banana  2021-09-01  2021-09-04     y     x   True  2021-02-04
5  banana  2021-12-31  2022-01-04     y     y   True  2021-02-04
```